# Stop EditText from bringing up the keyboard on Activity start?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an Edit Text in one of my App layouts, and I want this EditText to only open the keyboard (I believe this is called being focused on?) when it is actually touched.

As of now, the keyboard opens with the EditText whenever the app opens, which isn't what I want.

I have tried many different XML tags to fix this:

```
android:focusable="false" <--- Prevents keyboard from opening at all.

android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode = "true"     <--- These tags give me the same result as no tags (keybaord will open on activity start)

android:focusedByDefault = "true" <--- Only available in API >= 23
```

What I am asking is, why is it so hard to disable default focus on an EditText? Surely I am missing an easy way to do this.

EDIT: Adding this line to my AndroidManifest fixed the issue:
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
However, I don't like this solution. It seems like since this is in the Manifest, it will affect more UI elements than the single EditText I need to change.

Comment: Add this line in Manifest.xml `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Alternatively you can set the focus to the root layout element:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

**Example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <EditText
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This seems like the best way to do it. Thank you!

Comment: You are very welcome. I'm happy if the solution is good for you. I do not know this is the best way, but certainly a working version I know.

Answer (score 3):

Use `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`

If you dig deep into the Theme you are using for your Activity, you will find that the default value of `windowSoftInputMode` is `stateUnspecified|adjustPan`. And from the documentation:

`stateUnspecified`: Not specified, use what the system thinks is best. This is the default.

So depending on the the android device you run, your results will vary. I tried reproducing your case in API-26 emulator and the keyboard doesn't show up.You can use `stateHidden` to ensure that when an activity starts, the soft keyboard doesn't show up when the EditText gets focused on itself.

The other way to solve this is to `requestFocus` to some other element in the UI, making sure the EditText is not the first UI element to get focused. In my experience this is kind of a hack and it messes up the accessibility. The safest and clean way to accomplish is actually to use `stateHidden`.

`stateHidden`: Make the soft input area hidden when normally appropriate (when the user is navigating forward to your window).

Note that this will not affect any other UI elements. You can use `adjustPan` also to this, based on the screen background.